# iPhone 3.0 WebView Scroll PDF Error - [NSCFDictionary _absoluteLinkURL]

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, webview

I have a WebView which loads a PDF file:

```
[myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL 
fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName
ofType:@"pdf"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

It works fine on iPhone OS 2.x but on iPhone 3.0, when I tap the PDF for scrolling, this error appears, and the app crash:

> -[NSCFDictionary _absoluteLinkURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x1c0230 Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[NSCFDictionary
>   _absoluteLinkURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c0230'

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSString *urlAddress = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try putting this on a separate line:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName
ofType:@"pdf"]isDirectory:NO];
```

and then seeing what

```
NSLog(@"path: %@",path);
```

outputs.

Just to make sure you are getting what you expect, I'm not sure of the nuances between 2.x and 3.0 in regards to these calls, it's just my 2 cents in helping you with your issue.